# Performance testing of an app - Cloud foundry

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, performance-testing, cloud-foundry

Pivotal cloud foundry abstracts VM, containers, OS process

---

In cloud foundry, deployment unit is an application

---

But in production, application may give memory leaks, high CPU core usage, high number of I/O(file descriptors), virtual memory size of an application process in runtime, huge number of database connections which is easy to track with an application running directly on a Linux VM.

Application can be a multi process application or it can be a multithreading application. So, it becomes important to track(test) the number of threads or child process launched in runtime.

---

How to do such performance testing of an app in Cloud foundry?

Answer (score 2):

In what relates to performance testing per si, you are not required to do it on cloudfoundry, most CF apps can be run as standalone applications. The tools used for testing are more related to the technology and SDK.

The most common type CF apps are web apps, there are several [open source performance testing tools](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/web-performance-testing-top-12-free-open-source-tools-consider) that can help you with that.

If instead of performance testing, you want to do performance measurement of applications running under CF, you can use the [CF Top](https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/#top) plugin.

Comment: Do you mean, multi-process or multi-thread applications are not meant to be run on cloudfoundry?

Comment: `Do you mean, multi-process or multi-thread applications are not meant to be run on cloudfoundry?` You are certainly able to run those on CF.

Comment: Accurate performance testing requires a controlled environment and tests you can repeat to get the same results. That way you can test, measure, investigate, improve your app and retest your app to check that your improvements worked. CF is a dynamic environment so it's very difficult to run a test, repeat that test and get consistent results. This is because the placement of your app is abstracted away and handled by the platform. In addition, you do not know what else is running on a Cell with your app. The way CPU limits are enforced also makes performance testing difficult.

Comment: @DanielMikusa , such strict definition for "performance accuracy" would only be possible if you have full control of the HW and SW behavior, including OS. If you really want to go into that level, you can setup an "Accurate" cloud foundry platform that is dedicated to the application you want to measure.

Comment: @JoãoPinto - To each their own, but that's a lot of overhead to test something you could test in a couple regular VMs :)